# What is the pronunciation of "Software"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have heard the pronunciation of the word Software as "softwher".But recently i've heard Steve Jobs saying "sofwher" in a YouTube video.

link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vN4U5FqrOdQ

Comment: The T is pronounced.  However, it isn't rare that some people elide together strings of adjacent consonants.

Comment: It weally depends where you are from.

Comment: As usual, the stop in the center of the cluster /ftw/ gets elided to a tongue gesture that is rarely audible. What most people [mospipəl] hear is [sɔfwɛr].

Comment: Steve Jobs talks funny.  But the "T" in "software" (and other words with an embedded "T" sound) is "swallowed" to a greater or lesser degree by different speakers, and even by the same speaker in different contexts.

Answer (score 3):

This is called an elision, and it's a concern of preference, habit, or locale.

Some of my personal elisions:

- the *d* in **grandfather**
- the second *e* in **vegetable**
- the *t* in **scripts** (and many other t followed by s, see below)

Some elisions by others that I pronounce:

- the *i* in **family**
- the second *e* in **temperature**

Aside from a loosely-enforced "rule" that ts and d be elided if they occur between two other consonants (as in my above "scripts"), this is a subjective topic. It depends whether or not you abide the "rule" that *d* and *t* be elided if they occur between consonants. If you do, then Jobs has shown his command of an English intricacy. If you don't worry about such details, then you shouldn't be bothered.

Comment: Good answer, although I think something is backwards in the last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks @BraddSzonye, typing from phone at lunch. What's backwards?

Comment: If you abide (accept) the elision, then Jobs's elision should be fine. Perhaps you meant something other than abide?

Comment: @BraddSzonye quite right, my fault for trying to include hyperbole.

Comment: Great to know!..